# Trouble accessing the iPhone 4s smiley emoticons / icons

Tags: keyboard, iphone, ios, emoji

I just got a "new to me" iPhone 4s, set it up, and updated it to the most recent version of iOS v 8.2. This is my first iPhone, and though I've searched using Siri, Google, and the Stack Exchange search, I've been unable to find a solution to my problem

While using the built-in keyboard, I noticed the smiley face button that brings up the smiley emoticon keyboard. In addition to the 4 other emoticon keyboards along the bottom, I noticed that there is an varying array of dots along the top of each of the emoticon keyboards.

I'm use to to this indicating that there are other "pages" of whatever I'm looking at, and I only need to swipe left or right to see them. But swiping across the emoticons simply selects one icon after another, leaving the unseen emoticons unseen.

For the "face" icons, I see 1 black and 8 grey, I assume that means there are 8 other face style icons I can choose from, maybe smiling, or angry, or sleepy. Or at least 8 pages of my other face type emoticons to choose from.

But I can't figure out how to switch pages!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings > General > Keyboards > Add New Keyboard and choose Emoji. The full range of available emoji will become available through the 'globe' icon to the right of the '123' icon.

Comment: It already says "Emoji" below "English". The globe key brings up the English keyboard.

Comment: Oddly though, removing the Emoji keyboard and re-adding it now allows me to swipe through the other pages of faces! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!